# Using heartbeat with systemd

Tags: cluster, systemd, drbd, heartbeat

I'm using a simple setup with heartbeat handling a shared filesystem implemented with drbd and served via apache.
I'm using /etc/ha.d/haresources to define the ha resource, this way:

```
server1 drbddisk::myfs \
Filesystem::/dev/drbd/by-res/myfs::/mnt/myfs::ext4::noatime \
IPaddr::10.0.0.254/24/eth0 apache2
```

This works fine if using the old debian sysvinit, but has a race problem with systemd because stopping apache is done asyncronously, so when heartbeat issue the "/etc/init.d/apache2 stop" scrypt while it returns very quickly, apache2 can still be active and hence the unmount of the FS fails.

I know a lot of workarounds to solve this problem but I would like to know if there is a "clean" way, without having to revert to sysvinit

Comment: If you are doing this for a new project, I think it's better you switch to corosync+pacemaker

Comment: it's not new, it is the upgrade of a debian system to jessie, which uses systemd by default

Comment: Defaults can be changed.  All my Jessie systems stilll run sysvinit.

Comment: I know, that's why I wrote "I know a lot of workarounds", and I'm interested to solve the problem using systemd, that I enjoy using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Systemd itself (on Debian 8) is just using the good old init-scripts.

```
user@server:~> systemctl status apache2
apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2015-02-12 13:24:34 CEST; 7 weeks 8 days ago
  Process: 24775 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/apache2 stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 9475 ExecReload=/etc/init.d/apache2 reload (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 24799 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

That's not a systemd problem. Systemds 'systemctl' also doesn't work asynchronously by default. That's what the `--no-block` option is for. You're also probably not using systemd-tools at all when issuing commands like that in heartbeat.

Comment: I probably misdiagnosed something. Thanks for the insight